# BFS(breadth first search) compiler output is not following as per my understanding

Tags: python, data-structures, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have python code for Breadth first search  (bfs):

```
from collections import deque
def bfs(graph, start):
    visited = set()
    queue = deque([start])
    # print('queue',queue)
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        # print("vertex",vertex)
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            print(vertex)
            queue.extend(graph[vertex].difference(visited))

# example graph
graph = {'A': {'B', 'C'},
        'B': {'A', 'D', 'E'},
        'C': {'A', 'F'},
        'D': {'B'},
        'E': {'B', 'F'},
        'F': {'C', 'E'}}

# start BFS from vertex 'A'
bfs(graph, 'A')
```

after traversal by hand, it gives output as A,B,C,D,E,F
but compiler output says A,C,B,F,D,E

Why is this?

Comment: No C++ content here, tag removed, no AI content either.

Comment: My guess for the answer (but knowing nothing about python) is that the operation `queue.extend(graph[vertex].difference(visited))` is not adding the vertices in the order you think it is. Why not print the queue before and after that operation.

Comment: In Python a set is an unordered collection, so you cannot assume any order of neighbors from your initial graph structure.

Comment: Simply put, both are correct. The order is A -> [B, C] -> [D, E, F]. How elements inside each of these groups are ordered doesn't matter. Because the sets are unordered, they can output their elements in any order.

Comment: `A,C,B,F,D,E` is legitimate BFS traversal of the graph.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `artificial-intelligence`?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `graph[vertex].difference(visited)` doesn't have a particular order of elements, on different runs you will get different orders.

If you require a particular order, you will need to impose that after doing the set difference. E.g. `sorted(graph[vertex].difference(visited))` will ensure elements are added in alphabetic order.

```
from collections import deque
def bfs(graph, start):
    visited = set()
    queue = deque([start])
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            print(vertex)
            queue.extend(sorted(graph[vertex].difference(visited)))

# example graph
graph = {'A': {'B', 'C'},
        'B': {'A', 'D', 'E'},
        'C': {'A', 'F'},
        'D': {'B'},
        'E': {'B', 'F'},
        'F': {'C', 'E'}}

# start BFS from vertex 'A'
bfs(graph, 'A')
```